# RxJS - How can I map/switch a Subject Observable and add a mean calculation to every emitted value?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex, rxjs6

I'm fairly new to RxJS and I want to do the following:

Imagine I'm writing a method to track temperatures over time. This method would observe a Subject that will emit values like the following: `[12, 49, -2, 26, 5, ...]`

How can I turn this into another Observable which adds the mean over time for every value as they come?

```
[
  {
    temperature: 12,
    mean: 12
  },
  {
    temperature: 49,
    mean: 30.5
  },
  {
    temperature: -2,
    mean: 19.67
  },
  {
    temperature: 26,
    mean: 21.25
  },
  {
    temperature: 5,
    mean: 18
  },
  ...
]
```

The difficulty I'm struggling with is that mean calculation should be done using ALL previous values.

Is there a way to do this? I actually need to add more data and calculate other values as well, but this is the gist of what I need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a scan like you would with reduce on an array. Pass in a starting accumulator with { num: 0, total: 0, mean: 0 } and each iteration increment the num, add the current temp to the total temp and calculate the mean. Thinking about observables as arrays that happen over time can help visualising them sometimes.

```js
const { from, timer, zip } = rxjs;
const { scan } = rxjs.operators;

const temps = [12, 49, -2, 26, 5];

// Let's do it with an array
console.log(
  temps.reduce(
    (accumulator, temp) => ({
      num: accumulator.num + 1,
      temp: temp,
      total: accumulator.total + temp,
      mean: (accumulator.total + temp) / (accumulator.num + 1)
    }),
    { num: 0, temp: 0, total: 0, mean: 0 }
  )
);

const temps$ = from(temps);

const timer$ = timer(0, 1500);

var tempsOverTime$ = zip(temps$, timer$, (temp, _) => temp);

// Now let's do the same thing with an observable over time.
tempsOverTime$
  .pipe(
    scan(
      (accumulator, temp) => ({
        num: accumulator.num + 1,
        temp: temp,
        total: accumulator.total + temp,
        mean: (accumulator.total + temp) / (accumulator.num + 1)
      }),
      { num: 0, temp: 0, total: 0, mean: 0 }
    )
  )
  .subscribe(a => {
    console.log({ temp: a.temp, mean: a.mean });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```